# Nuxt 3 Server readBody(): 500 error: The first argument must be of type string or..... only on production

Tags: firebase, vuejs3, firebase-hosting, nuxtjs3

I'm working on a Nuxt 3 project, where for the first time I'm also looking at the server side. I have made a server route which I call in a Pinia store. On my local machine it works as expected. But when I deploy to Firebase hosting (Prod) I get a 500 error....

The error I get is:

```
  "url": "/api/chat-completion",
  "statusCode": 500,
  "statusMessage": "",
  "message": "The first argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, ArrayBuffer, or Array or an Array-like Object. Received an instance of Object",
  "stack": ""
}
```

I call my Nuxt server endpoint in my Pinia store like this:

```
async function doSomething(formData: ApplicationInfo) {
    if (userStore.userData.credits > 0) {

      try {
        const data = await $fetch<string>('/api/chat-completion', {
          method: 'POST',
          body: formData
        })

        if (data) {
         // do stuff
        }

      } catch (e) {
      }
    } else {
    }
  }
```

I have created:  `server/api/chat-completion.ts` Which looks like this:

```
import { ApplicationInfo } from '../../types/applicationInfo.interface'

export default defineEventHandler(async (event): Promise<string> => {
  const body: ApplicationInfo = await readBody<ApplicationInfo>(event)
  const response = await chatCompletion(body)
  return response
})
```

ApplicationInfo is an object.

By removing everything inside my defineEventHandler() function and putting code back one by one, I have been able to figure out the problem lays with the readBody() function.

I have followed the exact code from https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/server#handling-requests-with-body and it works on local. When I deploy to my production env on Firebase hosting it doesn't work...

Can anyone help me out with this one?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const body = event.node.req.body || await readBody(event);
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?